# create hour live(online)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create a local hour(`time zone -> UTC + 3:30`) with seconds?
**I not want use of plugin.**

I don't use of the following example because it gets the time of computer. It is only for display of what I want.
**EXAMPLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/

With respect

Answer (score 0):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/1/) and a list of GMT [offsets](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/definition/)

Source: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329

Comment: Exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/
only, not receive time of user computer

Comment: @Sheik, what made you choose the other answer? I'm wondering what I can do to improve my answers in the future?

Comment: ok. how to change the GMT in iran? how set this clock with change GMT in iran?

Comment: Thanks, But I mean here is that [changes GMT(+4.5 and +3.5) in Iran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Standard_Time) Every six months in year, and changes Time is pulled back and forth (Daylight Saving), I'm doing with this situation? (now GMT in iran is +4.5)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to output a string, a simple option might look like this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setUTCHours( date.getUTCHours() + 3, 
                  date.getUTCMinutes() + 30);

var output = 'hour: ' + date.getUTCHours() + ' minute: ' +date.getUTCMinutes();
// output is currently "hour: 0 minute: 16"
```

See jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/CZrWz/

Comment: Exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/
only, not receive time of user computer

Comment: @nrabinowitz's solution is ok. getUTCblahblah gets time in UTC+0, it's uninfluenced by user's local time.

Comment: @Paweł Kosiński - solution not is ok. i want exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/

Comment: how to change the GMT in iran? how set this clock with change GMT in iran?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The example above should render UTC/GMT + 3:30, which is the time difference for Iran - what more do you want?